# Apache camel with fileExist using TryRename

Tags: file, apache-camel

Can somebody give me some light how this "fileExist=TryRename" with "tempFileName" really works. If the "tempFileName" (temporary.txt) is existed in the directory then it will be renamed to the actual name which is (original.txt). Is my understanding correct? Or Its the other way around but this can be achieved by "fileExist=Move" and "moveExisting".

file:/tmp/?fileName=orginal.txt&fileExist=TryRename&tempFileName=temporary.txt

Comment: hey Kits ! I think you can find some helps in [The official documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.12.x/file-component.html)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @AbdelghaniRoussi 

It says in the documentation that "fileExist=TryRename is only applicable if tempFileName option is in use. This allows to try renaming the file from the temporary name to the actual name, without doing any exists check. This check may be faster on some file systems and especially FTP servers."

My understanding is that if incoming file exist already then it will use the tempFileName option?

Comment: My objective before when posting this is to not overwrite the existing and use different file name for incoming file without doing any checks in the directory.
I thought this can be achieved by "fileExist=TryRename" with "tempFileName" option but it keeps overwriting the existing file.